# Find the determinant of the matrix A with this linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, linear-transformations

Consider a linear transformation $T(x) = Ax$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$. Suppose for two vectors $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ in $\Bbb R^2$ we have $T(\vec v_1) = 5 \vec v_2$ and $T(\vec v_2)=-6 \vec v_1$. Find the determinant of the matrix $A$.

Comment: I've gotten hints where you could have 2 cases where $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ could be linearly independent or dependent, but I am not sure how I could use this. Also that there's a lack of information to create a matrix for the linear transformation.

Comment: For two vectors to be linearly dependent, one must be a scalar multiple of the other.  But that is not possible given the information about how $T$ acts on these two vectors.  So you may give the case $v_1,v_2$ linearly independent your attention.

Comment: @user1766555: information such as that provided in your comment above should be placed into your main question as an [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, you need to assume $v_1,v_2$ are nonzero. Then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are independent, because otherwise $v_1=kv_2$ and then $-6k^2 v_2 =k Av_2 = Av_1= 5v_2 $ which gives $k^2<0$.

Then write $A$ in the basis $(v_1,v_2)$, and it has the form 
$$\pmatrix{0 & 5 \\ -6 & 0}$$
so the determinant is $30$.

Comment: I don't understand why there's $k^2$.

Comment: We have $Av_2= - 6v_1 = -6kv_2$. So multiplying both by $k$, we get $-6k^2 v_2=kAv_2$

Comment: I think you have a typo with $-6k^2v_2$. Shouldn't it be $-6k^2v_1$? Also why does $Av_1=kAv_2$?

Comment: So, I'm assuming the two vectors are dependent, and thus one is k times the other for some k. I don't think there's a typo

Comment: It's just confusing to read to me. I still don't understand it.